# Characters not showing up [C]

Tags: c

I'm making a fun little text-based game for fun and for some reason some text aren't showing up for the username.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Forward declarations -- Prototypes */
void askCharacterName(char *name);
void printMainMessage(char* name);

int main(char* username) {
    askCharacterName(username);
    char* temp;
    temp = &username;
    printMainMessage(temp);
    return (0);
}

void askCharacterName(char *name) {
    char username[20];
    printf("What is your desired username?");
    scanf("%s", &username);
    return *username;
}

void printMainMessage(char *name) {
    printf("Hello %s. Welcome to Lamescape!\n", name);
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Welcome []. Welcome to Lamescape!
```

Comment: The function `askCharacterName` do not modify `name` parameter...

Comment: `temp = &username`?????

Comment: `return` from `void` function?

Comment: @KirilKirov, Yeah. Trying to return the char from a void function.

Comment: Needless to say, there are more erroneous lines than there are correct ones in this code.

Comment: I've got the feeling that you make rules about C as you go. Start by reading a book, doing an tutorial.

Comment: @bolov, Noted. Any clues on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Team41: consider re-writing the program, it has many problems: returning from void, not using main properly, invalid pointer assignment ...

Comment: You can't just randomly put `*` and `&` all over the show and hope it works

Comment: @Team41 The better question would be to ask what you aren't doing wrong. There is more errors then correct code in this. I recommend you take a traditional c tutorial or class or read a book.

Comment: Well the only correct thing in this piece of code is the name "Lamescape".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Your main function should have a different signature.
- Consider allocating your memory at a higher level so it is available in lower
  levels of the program.
- When modifying buffers in c, always pass their size too.
- Functions with void return values are not expected to return anything.

After fixing these problems your errors went away.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Forward declarations -- Prototypes */
void askCharacterName(char *name, unsigned size);
void printMainMessage(char* name, unsigned size);

int main()
{
    char namebuffer[100];
    askCharacterName(namebuffer, 100);
    printMainMessage(namebuffer, 100);
    return 0;
}

void askCharacterName(char *name, unsigned size)
{
    printf("What is your desired username?");
    scanf("%s", name);
}

void printMainMessage(char *name, unsigned size)
{
    printf("Hello %s. Welcome to Lamescape!\n", name);
}
```

Passing the size has no immediate effect here. I leave it up to you to figure out how to ensure that the buffer is never used beyond its bounds.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information! I'm still really new to C and pointers so it's kind of confusing for me. I'm only in 9th grade and my school doesn't offer any CS courses. :P

Comment: @Team41 welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The `username` in `askCharacterName` has its memory content at the program stack.

```
void askCharacterName(char *name) {
    char username[20];
    printf("What is your desired username?");
    scanf("%s", &username);
    return *username;
}
```

Allocating the space in **heap** for `username` in `main` looks to be what you are looking for.